# How can I do two api call one after other with switchmap in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How can I do for example such thing with rxjs in Angular?
If I have two api call and I want it that first is ready I want to add some delay to it and run the other one.I would like to do it with switchmap reactive way.How looks like it in rxjs?

```
apiCall1();
delay
apiCall2();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
apiCall1().pipe(
   delay(1000),
   switchMap(() => apiCall2())
);
```